# Install Magento1 in Localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, localhost

I downloaded database of my Magento 1.9.8.3 and imported .sql file in Database of my localhost . Then I tried to install Magento 1.9.8.3 code . But I am getting below error.

[image]

I got below code in `436346350574` file.

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:545:"Error in file: "/var/www/html/magento1final/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'admin_assert' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `admin_assert` (
  `assert_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Assert ID' ,
  `assert_type` varchar(20) NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Assert Type' ,
  `assert_data` text NULL COMMENT 'Assert Data' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`assert_id`)
) COMMENT='Admin Assert Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci";i:1;s:976:"#0 /var/www/html/magento1final/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /var/www/html/magento1final/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.1.2')
#2 /var/www/html/magento1final/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.1.2')
#3 /var/www/html/magento1final/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /var/www/html/magento1final/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /var/www/html/magento1final/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /var/www/html/magento1final/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/magento1final/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:50:"/magento1final/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/";s:11:"script_name";s:24:"/magento1final/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

What is the solution ?

Comment: are you trying to setup existing magento database with, fresh files ?

Comment: you don't need to run setup again. just change new database detail at `app/etc/local.xml` and change URL in database in `core_config_data` table.

Comment: Thanks @Pawan. I tried to import `core_config_data` table and got this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfYNi.png

Comment: do you have any other magento 1.x  installation ?

Comment: @Pawan, Yes, I have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85608/discussion-between-pawan-and-abu-abu).

Comment: have you setup it successfully ?

Comment: Welcome and No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Pawan said, if there's no `app/etc/local.xml` file, then when you run Magento it will try first installing the system database.

It will throw an error because you already have a database with those tables in there so it cannot install.

Since you already have a database, all you need to do is add the `app/etc/local.xml` file to your local instance and change the details in that file to point to your local database with the correct username and password.

Comment: Thanks @Haim. I tried to import `core_config_data` table and got this error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfYNi.png

Comment: Don't import the table. You said you have a copy of the database. So all you need to do is copy the FILE app/etc/local.xml and change the database info in the file